# Python Doing Math with Lists, Converting Lists to Matrices

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-2.7, matrix

I have two lists:

```python
list_1 = sorted(random.sample(xrange(1, 101), 10))
print list_1

list_2 = sorted(random.sample(xrange(1, 101), 10))
print list_2
```

Note: in my actual project, one of the lists is built from user input.

I then want to convert these to matrices and do some simple math. For example, perhaps invert one matrix from 1x10 to 10x1 so I can multiply them, or something like that.

How can I do this? I've read about packages like NumPy and SciPy, but I am very new to Python and don't know how to install these, or if I even need the functions they offer. I'd appreciate any advice.

Comment: If you're just dealing with numbers, then NumPy is probably what you want. It's included with most standard python distributions. It's documentation is [here](http://wiki.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial).

Comment: @aruisdante Thank you. When I try `from numpy import *` I get `ImportError: No module named numpy`. I am running Python 2.7.6 which I downloaded from python.org. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: NumPy is a separate library.  You can download the library from the [Python NumPy package page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy).

Comment: @pez you need to _install_ numpy. It does not come standard with python. Which OS are you using? It might be useful to checkout http://www.scipy.org/install.html

Comment: It's possible it's not installed on your system, see [here](http://www.scipy.org/install.html)

Comment: @Hooked I am using Windows 8.

Comment: @pez Great! Now install Anaconda or Enthought. They package a bunch of useful modules (like numpy as scipy) together. Report back here if the answer provided needs more help. Good luck!

Comment: @Hooked Thanks for the help. I downloaded Anaconda, but I'm not sure where to install it. Would just installing it here work best for calling functions from it in Python: C:\Users\pez\Anaconda. Also, should I register it as my default Python 2.7 and add it to my PATH environment variable?

Comment: @Hooked I went ahead and installed it with default settings and it is working well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic example of [inner products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) and [outer products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product):

```
import random
import numpy

list_1 = sorted(random.sample(xrange(1, 101), 10))
list_2 = sorted(random.sample(xrange(1, 101), 10))

A = numpy.array(list_1).reshape(1,10)
B = numpy.array(list_2).reshape(10,1)

# Inner product
print A.dot(B)

# Outer product
print A.T.dot(B.T)
```

with output like:

```
[[22846]]
[[   5   21   26   33   41   42   43   74   78   81]
 [  15   63   78   99  123  126  129  222  234  243]
 [ 105  441  546  693  861  882  903 1554 1638 1701]
 [ 110  462  572  726  902  924  946 1628 1716 1782]
 [ 135  567  702  891 1107 1134 1161 1998 2106 2187]
 [ 165  693  858 1089 1353 1386 1419 2442 2574 2673]
 [ 190  798  988 1254 1558 1596 1634 2812 2964 3078]
 [ 270 1134 1404 1782 2214 2268 2322 3996 4212 4374]
 [ 375 1575 1950 2475 3075 3150 3225 5550 5850 6075]
 [ 465 1953 2418 3069 3813 3906 3999 6882 7254 7533]]
```

Note that I use [`.dot`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) for matrix multiply. If you don't you get pairwise operations:

```
# Matrix multiply
C = numpy.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
print C.dot(C)

# Pairwise operation
print C*C
```

with the result:

```
[[ 7 10]
 [15 22]]
[[ 1  4]
 [ 9 16]]
```